# How to create a custom phone number regex

Tags: php, regex

I'm using php and searching for the right regex form my country phone number.
I'm not good with regex but i did some research on the possible patterns of my country phone number's and those are:

- 71 252 254
- 75 89 95 52
- +216 12 21 47 58
- 00216 12 54 11 25
- +216 12 789 541
- 00216 71 245 852

plz help me save my day !!

Comment: And what if people don't use the spaces in the correct way? Is that valid?

Comment: At least try something

Comment: Also, what if they enter something like `+216 (12) 789541`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming you removed all spaces (and perhaps other invalid characters):

```
((\+|00)216)?[0-9]{8}
```

This regex should match all provided examples.

**Update:**

Here is the "complete" regex. It is based on [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Telephone_numbers_in_Tunisia):

```
((\+|00)216)?(74|71|78|70|72|9|4|2|5|73|75|76|77|79)[0-9]{6}
```

What I don't know is how to handle single-digit *area codes*, perhaps the following regex is better:

```
((\+|00)216)?(74|71|78|70|72|09|04|02|05|73|75|76|77|79)[0-9]{6}
```

**Update 2:**

The final solution, this time based on [another document](http://www.wtng.info/wtng-216-tn.html):

```
((\+|00)216)?([2579][0-9]{7}|(3[012]|4[01]|8[0128])[0-9]{6}|42[16][0-9]{5})
```

Comment: This will also match `00491234`.

Comment: Right i should remove spaces it doesn't seem logical to put spaces in phone numbers. thx it work fine i test it on [link](http://regexpal.com/)

Comment: @HaithemRihane I seriously hope I got it but I am not sure. Is `+216 12 789 541` really valid?

Comment: `+216 12 789 541` is not a valid tunisian number and i test it on rexpal.com it refused it

Comment: @still_learning is this Regex Compatible with Data Annotation in c#

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
 if(preg_match(((\+|00)216)?[0-9]{8})) {
      // do something
    }
```

Or try following:

```
if (!preg_match('/^\+\d+$/', $phone)) 
    fail("Invalid phone number");
```

Comment: He wants to allow only phone numbers for his country.

Answer (score 0):

The general rule with phone numbers is simple to ignore spaces and dashes. After it you can count for the minimum and maximum number of digits and the optional plus sign.

```
$filteredPhone = preg_replace('/[^\+\d]/', '', $phone);
$phoneFormatOk = preg_match('/^(\+?0*216)?\d{8}$/', $filteredPhone);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with this validator symfony if you wont 
https://github.com/haithem-rihane/sfValidatorTnPhone

> /^((+|00)216)?([2579][0-9]{7}|(3[012]|4[01]|8[0128])[0-9]{6}|42[16][0-9]{5})$/